# Migrate Global Value Providers from Aura to LWC: how to detect browser in lightning web component?

Tags: migration, lightning-web-components, value-providers

For most Global Value providers there are equivalent @salesforce modules in LWC, except for [globalId](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/247659/3716)  and $Browser

[image]

Am I wrong? Is there any equivalent for $Browser global provider in LWC?

How to detect browser in lightning web component? Is this possible?

Should standard detection methods be used?

Also, is there any equivalent for `globalId` value provider?

Answer (score 1):

Although it’s true that @salesforce modules replace some GVPs, many GVPs are unnecessary and can be derived either using Salesforce APIs or another way.

For example, why would you need to go to the server to get information about the browser?

> Should standard detection methods be used?

Yes!

Answer (score 0):

In looking for a GVP for $SObjectType, I found this page.  You have probably already found this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/migrate-gvps.html) at this point, but they now have a $Browser GVP

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.